# highlighting a window in GNOME's window list

Tags: python, perl, gtk

In order to indicate activity, some applications (e.g. Pidgin) highlight their entry in GNOME's Window List panel widget (e.g. via bold font or flashing color). This indication is reset automatically when the window is activated.

I have a terminal application for which I would like to achieve the same thing (preferably via Perl, but Python would work too) - but I have no idea where to start. I imagine I'd first have to find the terminal window (based on window title) and then trigger some kind of GTK action.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a GTK application, use [`gtk_window_set_urgency_hint()`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-urgency-hint). If you have a terminal application, you can't really do that - with [libwnck](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libwnck/stable/) you can get information about other application's windows, but as far as I know you can't get a GtkWindow pointer to another application's window.

May I suggest using the terminal beep? Of course this isn't a sure way to attract the user's attention, but some terminals are able to flash the title bar instead of beeping, or such things.

Comment: Thanks - I've tested [set_urgency_hint](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-urgency-hint) with a minimal PyGTK sample, and it's exactly what I asked for (though you have to manually un-set this flag on focus, which is to be expected). I'll ask around whether there's any way to get GNOME Terminal's GtkWindow pointer. As for using the terminal bell, that might work if/when [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/272749) [feature](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=557593) is implemented.

Comment: Turns out modifying another process's GTK window is possible after all, using `wnck`'s `window_foreign_new`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really into GTK programming, but as far as i know you want to set an "URGENT"-Flag for the Window which should be highlighted. Maybe this will get you any further. :)

Comment: Thanks; I've added some details to ptomato's response below.